# Multiple file validation: "This value should be of type string"

Tags: symfony, validation, file-upload, symfony4, symfony-forms

I'm trying to use Symfony Validator on a file upload form (form extension's validation) and I'm getting this error message:

> **messageTemplate: "This value should be of type string."** from Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation

Upload works well without the validator, and I cant figure out where this message is coming from.

Here's my FormType, with a basic validation as doc's exemple:

```
    {
        $builder
            ->add('file', FileType::class, [
                'label' => 'Choisir un fichier',
                'mapped' => false,
                'multiple' => true,
                'constraints' => [
                    new File([
                        'maxSize' => '1024k',
                        'mimeTypes' => [
                            'application/pdf',
                            'application/x-pdf',
                        ],
                        'mimeTypesMessage' => 'Please upload a valid PDF document',
                    ])
                ],
            ])
        ;
    }
```

If I remove `maxSize`, `mimeTypes` and/or `mimeTypesMessage` arguments, I still have the same problem.

I can't use annotations on entity (mapped option is set to `false`).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The error is due to the `File` constraint expecting a filename, but since the field has the option `multiple` is actually receiving an array. To solve it, you have to wrap the constraint in another [`All`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/All.html) constraint, that will apply the inner constraint (`File` in this case) to each element of the array.

Your code should look like this:

```
    ->add('file', FileType::class, [
      'label' => 'Choisir un fichier',
      'mapped' => false,
      'multiple' => true,
      'constraints' => [
        new All([
          'constraints' => [
            new File([
              'maxSize' => '1024k',
              'mimeTypesMessage' => 'Please upload a valid PDF document',
              'mimeTypes' => [
                'application/pdf',
                'application/x-pdf'
              ]
            ]),
          ],
        ]),
      ]
    ])
```